# Problem in numbering and showing the references

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

Does anyone knows why the numbering is weird like this?
How can I fix it?

```
Coscia M. Cosica, F. Gianootti, and D. Pedreschi,“ A Classification for Community Discovery Methods in Complex Networks,” CoRR as/1206.3552 (2012)
[0] [1] F. Moradi, T. Olovsson, P. Tsigas, “ An Evaluation of Community Detection Algorithms on Large-Scale Email Traffic,” SEA 283-294 (2012)
```

Here is the .tex:

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{Coscia} M. Cosica, F. Gianootti, and D. Pedreschi,`` A Classification for Community Discovery Methods in Complex Networks," \emph{CoRR} as/1206.3552 (2012) \\
\bibitem{Moradi} F. Moradi, T. Olovsson, P. Tsigas, `` An Evaluation of Community Detection Algorithms on Large-Scale Email Traffic," \emph{SEA} 283-294 (2012)
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you! I have just worked with LaTex for designing Math worksheet and I am sort of new! Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \cite{Coscia,Moradi}

  \begin{thebibliography}{99}    %%<-- you have to give the width of largest number
    \bibitem{Coscia} M. Cosica, F. Gianootti, and D. Pedreschi,`` A Classification for Community Discovery Methods in Complex Networks," \emph{CoRR} as/1206.3552 (2012) 
    \bibitem{Moradi} F. Moradi, T. Olovsson, P. Tsigas, `` An Evaluation of Community Detection Algorithms on Large-Scale Email Traffic," \emph{SEA} 283-294 (2012)
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]